# Groovy - Filtering list by employer, role, project document ID, certification

Tags: grails, groovy

I am trying to figure out how to filter a list of users that will be going to a drop down menu by employer, role, project document ID, and if certified. I only users that meet all the requirements to be displayed on the list. I can not get the code to compile correctly. I am using too many ifs? Is there a better way to write it? Thank you for any help in advance.

I am attempting to filter the listed users by employer, role, and
if they have an active certification.

```
def assign_roles() {
    List documentAuthors = []
    List fieldTechnicians = []
    ProjectDocument projectDocument = ProjectDocument.get(params.id)
    Project project = Project.get(params.projectId)
    User authUser = docRegService.authenticatedUser
    def published_document = CertificationHistoryHeader.findAllByUserAndPublishedDocument(user, published_document)
    String employerAdminCertifier = CertifierDocument.findByDocument(projectDocument ? .document ? .document) ? .certifier.name

    EmployerUser.findAllByEmployer(authUser.employer) * .user.each {
      User user - >
        if (CertifierDocument.findByDocument(projectDocument ? .document ? .document) ? .certifier.name == employerAdminCertifier) {
          if (latest.action in [CertHistoryActions.CERTIFIED.toString(), CertHistoryActions.RE_CERTIFIED.toString()])
            if (user.hasRole(Roles.ROLE_DOCUMENT_AUTHOR.toString())) {
              documentAuthors.add(user)
            }
          if (user.hasRole(Roles.ROLE_FIELD_TECH.toString())) {
            fieldTechnicians.add(user)
          }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you do have syntax errors. You can't have spaces in the safe navigation operator (?.), the spread operator (*.), nor when declaring closure parameters (->). As for a better way to write it, here's my opinionated version:

```
def assign_roles() {
    List documentAuthors = []
    List fieldTechnicians = []
    ProjectDocument projectDocument = ProjectDocument.get(params.id)
    Project project = Project.get(params.projectId)
    User authUser = docRegService.authenticatedUser

    def published_document = CertificationHistoryHeader.findAllByUserAndPublishedDocument(user, published_document)
    String employerAdminCertifier = CertifierDocument.findByDocument(projectDocument?.document?.document)?.certifier.name  
    def isValidAction = latest.action in [CertHistoryActions.CERTIFIED.toString(), CertHistoryActions.RE_CERTIFIED.toString()]

    if(CertifierDocument.findByDocument(projectDocument?.document?.document)?.certifier.name == employerAdminCertifier)) {
        EmployerUser.findAllByEmployer(authUser.employer)*.user.each { User user ->
            def roles = EmployerUser.where {
                /* 
                 * A query to get all of the user's roles.
                 * This will depend on how EmployerUser and role domain classes are associated.
                 * The list can be limited to the two roles you're looking for.
                 */
            }.list()

            if(isValidAction && roles.contains(Roles.ROLE_DOCUMENT_AUTHOR)) {
                documentAuthors.add(user)
            }

            if(roles.contains(Roles.ROLE_FIELD_TECH)) {
                fieldTechnicians.add(user)
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Most of the conditions in the `user` *loop* don't seem to have anything to do with the user, so instead of evaluating them for every user, I do it once, prior to the loop. That in itself cleans up how the conditions are used in the loop. In fact, if the *employerAdminCertifier* condition is not met, I skip the entire loop.

Then, instead of calling `user.hasRoles()` twice I'd run a query to get the user's roles. Then use the resulting list. That cuts down on the database calls.